# How in a recycleview started the view by a condition

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a recycleview which works perfectly I go through an adapter.

on the other hand I would like this view to be displayed not at position 0 but at a position following the name, it is to make a classification by player and I do not see how to do it, searching in the recycleview is not the solution because it does not display the results before and after.

I think it is in the adapter that you have to modify the code attached

Thank you for your help

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();


public RecyclerAdapter (Context context,List<Product> products){
    this.mContext = context;
    this.products = products;
}


public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView mTitle, mPrice,mPosition;
 /*   private ImageView mImageView;*/
    private RatingBar mRate;
    private LinearLayout mContainer;

    public MyViewHolder (View view){
        super(view);

        mTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.product_title);
  /*      mImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.product_image);*/

        mPrice = view.findViewById(R.id.product_price);
        mContainer = view.findViewById(R.id.product_container);
   mPosition=view.findViewById(R.id.position);


    }
}


@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.products_list_item_layout,parent,false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final Product product = products.get(position);

    holder.mPosition.setText(position+1+"");
    holder.mPrice.setText(product.getNom());

    holder.mTitle.setText(product.getPoint());
   /* Glide.with(mContext).load(product.getImage()).into(holder.mImageView);*/



}
```

Comment: please try to be a bit more clear.

Comment: I have my list that appears with about fifty names and I would like that instead of manually looking for its position by scrolling the recycleview that it focuses directly on the player's line but always keeping the previous and next lines it is why do a search does not interest me because I would only have the line requested and not the others

thank you

Comment: Do you want your recycler view to scroll to specific position?

Comment: yes thats what i want to do thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite confuse. But... As per my understanding to your question, you have a list and you want to show it in recyclerview by username.

If I am right,

```
List<String> playerList = Arrays.asList("Ozil", "Odegard", "Son", "Kane", "Neymar");  
List<String> sortedList =playerList.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());     

//this will sort the list by name order and you can just simply attach it to recycler view
```

Please tell me if my understanding is wrong.

**EDIT**

I see. You want to scroll to the specific position. If you can simply get the Username, do like this.

```
int index = userList.indexOf("user1"); //this will return index of the user1

rv.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(index); //this will scroll to user1 position automatically
```

The above code will scroll to the User1 position. But User1 will not at position 1. I mean you can scroll up if you want.  To show User1 at the top of the list, please do the following.

```
int index = userList.indexOf("user1");

userList.remove(index); // will remove user1
userList.add(0,"user1); //will add user1 add the top
```

Comment: Good evening no, I have my list which appears correctly in my recycleview what I want to do for example TOTO is in the first position so he can see himself directly but MICKEY is in the middle of this list, I want that when MICKEY connects, I recover his name in the shared preferences, I want the recycle view to navigate to his name and I want him to keep his initial position in the list so that he can see his ranking compared to other people

Comment: I see. I have edited my code. If something misunderstanding, Please tell me.